# UITextField keyboard doesn't appear

Tags: iphone, uikit, keyboard, uitextfield

I have a very simple screen with an UITextField with the default configuration, nothing special.
When I touch the UITextField, the keyboard doesn't pops up.
 I haven't any custom control, behavior or anything else, just that, but it doesnt'work.
I've done this in previous apps iPhone/iPad apps already on the AppStore but i can't figure out what's going wrong here.

The UITextField is created in Interface Builder, in the nib file.
I've been doing some research and i added an IBAction in the UIViewController for UItextField TouchDown event and the IBOutlet for the UITexField.
In the first line of the code i added:

```
[textFild becomeFirstResponder];
```

That's the default behavior of the UITextField, when you touch it, it becomes the first responder asking the system to show the keyboard.
I debugged it and it runs that line, but the keyboard still doesn't shows up.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you create this UITextField?

Comment: it would be good if you post the code to create the uitextfield

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I already figured out by myself!
I had tha UITextField in a UIViewController that gets presented from another view controller 
who responds to motion events, and that previous View Controller was allways the First Responder.
All I had to do was everytime i leave the controller's view in viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated, i called [self resignFirstResponder]; and that was all.

Answer (score 11):

Many times your code is right, it's just about the settings of your Xcode or the Simulator.

Try Toggling Keyboard Software in the Simulator

`Simulator --> Hardware --> Keyboard --> Toggle Software Keyboard`

OR just simply hit `Command + K` it would do the same thing

Comment: That was my problem too. In my case, it happened when I tried to enter text to a TextField using the **physical keyboard** of the Mac I was running the Simulator in. Doing so automatically closes the simulated keyboard, and you have to manually open it again with `Command + K`. Maybe it would be useful to add that explanation to your answer.

Answer (score 6):

One thing you should check is to make sure the containing view (the **UIView** that contains all the controls), which is the View icon in Interface Builder nib viewer, has **User Interaction Enabled** checked. If the parent container doesn't have this checked, even if the individual controls do, you will see this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I took me a while to find this silly oversight, but make sure that both properties of UITextView: selectable and editable are set to true.

Answer (score 0):

Its a pretty basic thing but make sure your **USER INTERACTION** and **ENABLED** are checked in the storyboard editor.