# UITextField keyboard doesn't appear when placed near bottom of view

Tags: ios, iphone, uiscrollview, keyboard, uitextfield

I've created two UITextFields on a content view controller that is placed over a UIScrollView.

I've made the very first view work as free-form so I could elongate it a bit, in order to fit the contents of my content view screen.

While the first UITextField has the keyboard appear when you press on it for editing, the second one (which is further down in the view) does not have the keyboard appear.

I theorized that the UITextField may be too low in the screen for the keyboard to appear, but when I raised it just enough, the keyboard began to appear.

Have a look:

[image]

While the above works, the one below does not:

[image]

I'm not sure if this question was already covered at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3589707/uitextfield-keyboard-doesnt-appear).

thanks in advance.

Comment: is the cursor blinking in the textfield?

Comment: @VenkatS.Rao, nope, it doesn't even let me click it to access the UITextField; I might as well be clicking on the view itself.

Comment: Then some other view is covering it and eating the clicks. If you can see it, and it has its delegate set to your view controller, then the only explanation is a nearly transparent view is sitting over it.

Comment: I don't think so, because when I look at my view structure, both UITextFields are on the content view, and the content view is the top view, above both the scrollview and view.